How to run/stop/remove long running task in nodejs
I have long running process/task that import data from one server into another
and from  business requirements i should be able to start/stop/delete this process/task
while it's running (active state) i've tried bullmq but it does not support aborting the process while it's active (issue) is there another way to do this before i move the entire thing to go or python
